# cordova: FileEntry metadata are undefined

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-file

```
cache_dir_entry.getFile(cache.program_list_cache, {create:true}, function(cache_file_entry) {

    console.log (cache_file_entry.name);
    console.log ("-" + cache_file_entry.lastModifiedDate);
    console.log ("-" + cache_file_entry.size );
 ...
 }
```

**I can see the file `name`, but both `lastModifiedDate` and `size` are `undefined`. Why?**

Note that in the real code I'm handling the failure event of `getFile` and I can succesfully `remove()` the `FileEntry`, so the object and the file both exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to use the `.file` function

```
cache_dir_entry.getFile(cache.program_list_cache, {create:true}, function(cache_file_entry) {

                    cache_file_entry.file(function(file) {
                        console.log (file.name);
                        console.log ("-" + file.lastModifiedDate ) ;
                        console.log ("-" + time_difference)
                        console.log ("-" + file.size ); 
                    });
```